# MVC Business Logic versus Display/UI Logic

Tags: asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, razor, separation-of-concerns

So, I'm using the code below to show a couple of elements on the page on initial load.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function(){
        @if (ViewBag.PageFunction == "Edit" && Model.ProductType.ProductTypeName == "Book")
        {
            @:$('#product-isbn').show();
        }

        @if (ViewBag.PageFunction == "Edit" && Model.HasBulkDiscount == true)
        {
            @:$('#product-bulk-discount').show();
        }
    });

</script>
```

We've recently moved to MVC and my manager and a co-worker are telling me that the top control structure is business logic but the bottom one is not business logic, and that I should not have business logic in my view.

I disagree and feel like this is perfectly valid code to have in my view. Am I right or am I wrong?

My manager also told me I shouldn't be using `@Html.LabelFor()` in my view either because it is not reusable. Here's an example of how I'm using it.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <p>@Html.LabelFor(p => p.ProductName, new { @class = "col-sm-12" })</p>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.ProductName, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Not sure if I understand that reasoning either.

Comment: For the 2nd one, your usage is correct and it creates a `<label>` associated with your textbox (no idea what you manager means by _not reusable_)

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure. He asked me, "Why not just type out the actual label instead of using the @Html.Labelfor?". I tried to explain this ties it to the model and if I'm using this label in multiple places then I just update the DisplayName attribute in the model and it will update everywhere it's used. He seems to have a real aversion to using Razor since he hasn't used it before and doesn't know it well.

Comment: Not using the HtmlHelper methods in a view is IMHO, just nonsense. They ensure that you html is always correctly generated.

Comment: Just as an add for the HtmlHelper discussion: I have heard similar conversations, and the peers were arguing that it's not _reusable_ because the `@Html.LabelFor()` call wasn't wrapped into their own abstraction and therefore when they needed to add some common functionality to the label "generator", they would need to go through each and every view looking out for the LabelFor calls...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MVC is ALWAYS part of UI and there is no business logic in the UI. The **view model** is not the business model, it's just data for the view, but it can contain some UI specific logic.

Your code is perfectly ok because it contains display logic i.e UI logic. `Html.LabelFor` is just a helper (not even a great one) that allows you to generate html faster. It helps with productivity and with maintainability, your manager should be interested in those aspects.

This types of helpers are way to small/granular to consider them reusable page elements/widgets. But you can build those using partials or directly in C# by creating your own Html Helpers (in which you can use the predefined helpers as well).

Comment: Thanks MikeSW. Manager has decided to not use any Razor code at all and to use strictly HTML/Knockout in the MVC app.

Answer (score 0):

I can understand your colleagues concern regarding logic in the view. One of the key principles of '[separated presentation](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html)' design patterns like MVC is that separating the components facilitates automated testing.

The argument against logic in the presentation components is that it reduces the amount of code that can be covered by automated tests as presentation components are usually more difficult to subject to automated testing.

If your view code was a simple `if (x == y) { show }` then there's no discussion. However, considering your logic is, slightly, more complex, in that you're `&&`'ing, I would ask how you could test that logic in an automated way? The fact that this logic is in the view makes that test harder than if it were in a non-presentation component (controller, etc.). In reality, this will need to be tested manually or via a front-end testing framework like [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/). Both methods that are more expensive than an automated unit, or integration test.

That said, if automated testing is not something your team values then you can put as much logic in your view as you wish. The whole solution will be tested via the front-end and the mechanisms that create the application's functionality will be opaque to the tester(s).